# Energy loss in a circuit during critical damping

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, energy, electric-circuits, harmonic-oscillator

I would like some intuitive explanation regarding impedance in an $RLC$ circuit.

So far, my understanding has been limited to underdamping situations where both resistance and reactance are present.

Suppose the resistance is big enough to cause critical damping and even over damping, how would the impedance turn out? And how does that affect energy loss in a $RLC$ circuit?

Comment: remember, $Z$ is the **absolute value** of the impedance, and you define it's real part and imaginary part with the angle $\Phi$. So your equation should actually read $Z = \sqrt{R^2 + X^2}$, where your X is the reactance of your inductor and cap.

Comment: The bit you have written for "calculating $/omega$ at critical damping is wrong. that is the imaginary bit of the quadratic you are trying to solve, so you forgot to add $\frac{-R}{2L}$ before the square root. The natural frequency of the system is defined by it's parameters and not by "us", So the frequency is actually $\frac{1}{sqrt{LC}}$, that would mean that $X_c + X_L = 0$.

Comment: @NeuroEng Thank you for the explanation. I am still trying to understand the this imaginary part of impedance. They seem matter when the circuit is underdamped and has to be taken into consideration for calculation?

Comment: in the square root you have written in your question, you can see how if the negative part is bigger than the positive part, you are going to end up with an imaginary number (under-damped), if equal (critically damped) or bigger (over damped), you will have only a real part. critical damping is somewhat the "transition" between these 2 domains (where the square root is 0(, if you think of your X-axis as real and Y-axis as imaginary in your S-domain, you can see how imaginary roots could cause oscillations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use the real components of the values. This means $X_C$ isn't in the equation and thus $Z$ is solvable. :)

Comment: If this is the case, I assume that $Z=R$ since angular frequency at critical damping approaches $0$, so $X_L \rightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what you do.